# All the pages go to my homepage

Tags: wordpress, redirect

On my website http://www.smithdesign.us all the pages go to my homepage.  I have tried a number of different things but so far nothing is working.
Any help is great.

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: What technology are you using to host this site? Since you're new, let me tell you that unless you put more supporting information your question will be quickly downvoted.

Comment: His question is tagged with "wordpress", so I suppose that's it.

Comment: Wordpress 3.4.1.  I have been removing all unneeded plugings

Answer (score 0):

Most likely something is messed up in your .htaccess file. Try removing its contents, resave your permalink structure, and if the .htaccess file is not automatically updated, update it with what Wordpress tells you to, then clear your browser cache and try again.

Comment: I will try that, the first time it did not work, but I have not tried clearing my cache.